# Freeswitch-rayo not found in docker hub

Tags: freeswitch, adhearsion

I Could not found the image dwilkie/freeswitch-rayo when running docker-compose pull from somleng-project repository (https://github.com/somleng/somleng-project).
Is it possible to build my own local docker image from github repository  (https://github.com/somleng/freeswitch-config/tree/master)? since it is linked to the docker image dwilkie/freeswitch-rayo.
Thanks,
(I hope to hear from @dwilkie)

Answer (score 0):

The image is moved to https://hub.docker.com/r/somleng/somleng-freeswitch

All of the images relating to Somleng have moved to https://hub.docker.com/r/somleng